# SSIS Package -Count based on multiple columns

Tags: ssis

I need to create an SSIS Package that provides me the count of workdoneby (contractor/company).

Input table from sql server db:

[image]

I need to count no of orders by contractor and company for a particular day + station + worktype + accountno.

My output should look like this.

[image]

Can someone help me how to create a package to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is in a table, you can ask the database engine to do the calculation logic.

### Setup

I created a temporary table and populated it with the supplied data.

```
CREATE TABLE
    #Source
(
    [Date] date
,   Station char(3)
,   worktype char(2)
,   Accountno varchar(10)
,   workdoneby varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO
    #Source
(
    Date
,   Station
,   worktype
,   Accountno
,   workdoneby
)
VALUES
    ('2018-06-24', 'RMS', 'RH', 'I.145.001', 'Company')
,   ('2018-06-24', 'RMS', 'PH', 'I.145.001', 'Contractor')
,   ('2018-06-24', 'RMS', 'PH', 'I.145.002', 'Company')
,   ('2018-06-24', 'RMS', 'PH', 'I.145.002', 'Contractor');
```

### Query time

Now let's query! I find it is helpful to break these problems down into smaller pieces. The first thing I want to do is break out the `workdoneby` column into two columns with a 1 or 0

```
SELECT
    S.Date
,   S.Station
,   S.worktype
,   S.Accountno
,   CASE S.workdoneby
        WHEN 'Contractor' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS contractorCount
,   CASE S.workdoneby
        WHEN 'Company' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS companyCount
FROM
    #Source AS S
```

Running that let's me look at the results and see I still have 4 rows and I get the correct entity counted.

The next step is to collapse/summarize/roll-up the values. You indicate we should group by date/station/worktype/accountno so that's exactly what we're going to to do.

I find it easier to debug if I take that first query and make it a derived table so the basic form now becomes `SELECT * FROM (ORIGINAL QUERY HERE) AS D` thus

```
SELECT
    D.Date
,   D.Station
,   D.worktype
,   D.Accountno
,   D.contractorCount
,   D.companyCount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        S.Date
    ,   S.Station
    ,   S.worktype
    ,   S.Accountno
    ,   CASE S.workdoneby
            WHEN 'Contractor' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS contractorCount
    ,   CASE S.workdoneby
            WHEN 'Company' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS companyCount
    FROM
        #Source AS S
) D
```

Now that you can see it's giving the same original results, we're going to use the `SUM` function on the contractorCount and companyCount columns and `GROUP BY` date/station/worktype/accountno

```
SELECT
    D.Date
,   D.Station
,   D.worktype
,   D.Accountno
,   SUM(D.contractorCount) AS contractor
,   SUM(D.companyCount) AS company
FROM
(
    SELECT
        S.Date
    ,   S.Station
    ,   S.worktype
    ,   S.Accountno
    ,   CASE S.workdoneby
            WHEN 'Contractor' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS contractorCount
    ,   CASE S.workdoneby
            WHEN 'Company' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS companyCount
    FROM
        #Source AS S
) D
GROUP BY
    D.Date
,   D.Station
,   D.worktype
,   D.Accountno;
```

### SSIS

Now that we have data looking as expected, within SSIS you need to do something with it. Your question doesn't specify *what* you need to do but likely you're going to use a `Data Flow Task` to push this aggregated data from one place to another destination (different server, Excel, etc) or you're going to push this data into a table on the same server in which case you're going to use an `Execute SQL Task`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was able to replicate this in my query and create an SSIS package that would delete the records available in destination DB and then insert the rows (output from sql query) into the destination db. Really appreciate the support.